# Sybase error: Fatal Error 804 occurred at. Please note the error and time, and contact

Tags: sybase

> Error  : WARNING - Fatal Error 804 occurred at %sysdate.  Please note the error and time, and contact a user with System Administrator (SA) authorization.

Does anyone knows what 804 error means ? i searched in many sites like this one [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917589.aspx)
and they are not helpful alot. thanks

Comment: First, it's a Sybase product, so you should probably check the Sybase documents.  Also, knowing which Sybase product (ASE, or ASA) will help.

Comment: @MichaelGardner  It ASE SQL, btw thanks it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 804 is a buffer pointer error.  Restarting the data server should clear the error, and it shouldn't reoccur.

Here's the [Sybase ASE documention](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00729.1500/html/errMessageAdvRes/BABEGAFG.htm) for that error.